# Delete all but newest -img directory

Tags: command-line, scripts, rm

I need help with a script that deletes all but the newest -img directories.

Contents of `/media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB2/`

```
01-16-18-img  
2018-01-26-11-img  
Clonezilla_Images  
Family_Movies_AND_PICS  
lost+found  
MAXTOR_SDB2  
sdb2_listing.txt  
SDB2_Mountpoint
```

Comment: Since you have just two `-img` folders, it's probably simplest to maually see which is newer and set `GLOBIGNORE` to that directory's name.

Comment: I don't see how GLOBIGNORE can work as those -img directories will have different names because of the dates in the file name.

Comment: If they didn't have different names they'd be the same directory, I'd suppose.